# Displaying models as a list of a particular attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a contacts model, with an attribute :area. I'd like to display one page (/listarea) as a list of all the areas. I have this part working

In contacts_controller.rb

```
def listarea
    @listarea = Contact.order(:area).uniq.pluck(:area)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contacts }
    end
  end
```

And the listarea.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover"> 
        <% @listarea.each do |area| %>
            <tr class="tablerow">
                <td><%= link_to area, :action => :areacontact, :area => area %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
</table>
```

I'd like to be able to click on the area and lead to another page (areacontact) which will show a full list of all the contacts in that :area. This part is not working.

In contacts_controller.rb I have

```
def areacontacts
    @contacts =  Contact.order(:name).find_all_by_area(params[:area])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contacts }
    end 
  end
```

And in areacontact.html.erb I have

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
    Hello
<% end %>
```

The error when I view /areacontact is

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your action name and view name should match if you want rails to automatically detect the view to render. I can see that your action is named `areacontacts` and your view is `areacontact.html.erb`

Comment: YESSSS! That's it. A pesky extra 's'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't  use **<%= link_to area, :action => :areacontact, :area => area %>** instead of use the path like areacontact_path check the proper path using rake routes. and 
In the line  **@contacts = Contact.order(:name).find_all_by_area(params[:area])** seems like no attributes are passing properly pleas check what are the params you are getting in the action.

Answer (score 0):

In your  contacts_controller.rb, you need some tweaks when u have nothing to show in the view. I mean when your database contacts tables is empty.

So you can do like this in  contacts_controller.rb

```
def areacontacts
  @contacts =  Contact.order(:name).find_all_by_area(params[:area]) rescue []
.....
...
end
```

You got error because of @contacts is not any result from your find_all_by_area query.

Also you can check nil in areacontact.html.erb before lopping  @contacts like this:

```
 <% if @contacts.present  %>

    <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
        Hello
    <% end %>

 <% end %>
```